# Adding SPNavigationNode Shows Incorrect Title

Tags: quick-launch, ssom, spnavigationnode

When adding a navigation node as like so:

```
foreach (SPNavigationNode node in web.Navigation.QuickLaunch)
{
    if (node.Title == "Parent Title")
    {
        SPNavigationNode newNode = new SPNavigationNode("Title I want", myList.DefaultViewUrl);
        node.Children.AddAsFirst(newNode);
    }
}
```

When the link is shown in quick launch it shows the name of `myList` as the title of the link instead of `Title I want` which was used in the `SPNavigationNode` constructor.

How do I get it to show `Title I want` instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
var node = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch[0];
string title = node.Title; 

SPNavigationSiteMapNode.UpdateSPNavigationNode(node
                    , null
                    , "NEW_TITLE"
                    , node.Url
                    , "DESCRIPTION"
                    , node.Properties["Target"].ToString()
                    , node.Properties["Audience"].ToString()
                    , true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a possibility. If you have more than one language installed in your farm, you need to take into consideration the title resource property:

```
     SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Announcements");
     if (list != null)
     {
       // Create a navigation node pointing to the Announcements list.
       SPNavigationNode newNode = new SPNavigationNode(list.Title, list.DefaultViewUrl);
       // Add the node to the Quick Launch area.
       SPNavigationNodeCollection quickLaunch = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
       quickLaunch.AddAsLast(newNode);

       // Copy translations of the list's title to the user resource for the node's title.
       string localizedTitle;
       foreach (CultureInfo culture in web.SupportedUICultures)
       {
          localizedTitle = list.TitleResource.GetValueForUICulture(culture);
          newNode.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture(culture, localizedTitle);
       }
       newNode.Update();
     }
```

In your case, if your current culture is en-US, just try to check the following to see if this is the issue:

```
foreach (SPNavigationNode node in web.Navigation.QuickLaunch)
{
    if (node.Title == "Parent Title")
    {
        SPNavigationNode newNode = new SPNavigationNode("Title I want", myList.DefaultViewUrl);
        newNode.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture("en-US","Title I want");
        node.Children.AddAsFirst(newNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Xavi, unfortunately, the title still doesn't change with your implementation.